# Pygame Collision interaction logical

Tags: python, pygame, collision, interaction

i am trying to simulate a collision in a runner game prototype. the problem is my logical to stop de character movement and make interact with the object.

I tried so many things but nothing.

here is my code: the problem is in the end

```
import pygame
import os

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
pygame.display.set_caption("shield hacking")
JogoAtivo = True
GAME_BEGIN = False
run =True
jumping =True;
# Speed in pixels per frame
speedX = 0
speedY = 0
cordX = 10;
cordY = 150;
groundX=0;
groundY=200;
verify = open('verify_continue.txt' , "r");
sound_trigger=False



def loadCoords():
    f1 = open( "coords.txt", "r")
    text=f1.read()
    num_list=text.split()
    print (num_list)
    cordX=num_list[0]
    print(cordX)
    cordY=num_list[1]
    f1.close()  
    return cordX,cordY


def copiaArquivo(cordX, cordY):
  x=str(cordX);
  y=" "+str(cordY);
  f1 = open( 'coords.txt', "w")
  f1.write(x);
  f2 = open( 'coords.txt', "w")
  f2.seek(2)
  f2.write(y);
  f1.close()
  f2.close()


def draw():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    ground = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (groundX, groundY,400, 10))
    square = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (cordX, cordY ,50, 50))
    enemy = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 155), (200, 150 ,50, 50));
    pygame.display.flip();


""" SCREEN(press START)  """ 
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 55);
text = font.render("Press A to Start", 1, (255, 0, 0));
screen.blit(text,(50,20));
pygame.display.update();


while JogoAtivo:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        print(evento)

    #verifica se o evento que veio eh para fechar a janela
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
               JogoAtivo = False
               copiaArquivo(cordX, cordY);
               pygame.quit();
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if evento.key == pygame.K_a:
                   print('GAME BEGIN')
                   GAME_BEGIN = True
                   sound_trigger = False
                   if verify.read()=="S":
                       cordX,cordY=loadCoords();
                       cordX = float(cordX);
                       cordY = float(cordY);
                   pygame.mixer.init();
                   if sound_trigger == True:
                       sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound('GunsNRoses_ParadiseRemix_xD.wav');
                       chan1 = pygame.mixer.find_channel()
                       chan1.queue(sound1);
            if evento.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                   speedX=-0.025
                   run= True;
            if evento.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                   speedX=0.025
                   run= True;
            if evento.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                   print("x ", cordX)
                   print("y " ,cordY)
                   speedY=-0.3
                   jumping= True;
                   if sound_trigger == True: 
                       sound2 = pygame.mixer.Sound('MMX2_SE_00019.wav');
                       chan2 = pygame.mixer.find_channel();
                       chan2.queue(sound2);
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYUP:
             if evento.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                   speedY=+0.2




    if GAME_BEGIN:
        draw();
        if run == True:   
            cordX+=speedX
        if jumping == True:
            cordY+=speedY

    """square = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (cordX, cordY ,50, 50))
    enemy = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 155), (200, 150 ,50, 50));"""


    """ground detection"""
    if cordY +50>= groundY:
            speedY=0

#PROBLEM HERE:
            """i think to use colliderRect() method could be easier"""

    if cordX+50 <=200 or cordX >=250:   #200 and 250 == object X coords
        cordY+=speedY;
        cordX+=speedX;
    elif cordX + 50 >=200 and cordX <=250 and cordY >=150:
            speedX=0;

    elif cordX + 50 >=200 and cordX <=250 and cordY + 50 >=150:
            speedY=0;

    """if cordX + 50 >=200 and cordX +50 <=250 and cordY >= 100:
            speedY=0;"""
```

Comment: use `pygame.Rect()` to keep position and size of object. And then you can use `rect.x`, `rect.y`, `rect.right` (=`rect.x+rect.width`), `rect.left`, `rect.top`, rect.bottom (=`rect.y+rect.height`), etc and `rect.colliderect(other_rect)`, `rect.collidepoint(mouse_position)` and `pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), rect)`. BTW: you don't have to assign `pygame.draw.rect()` to variable if you don't use this variable later.

Comment: BTW: Python doesn't need `;`

Comment: why do you open the same file two times to write two elements - open once and use `write()` two times.

Comment: organize code - first constants, next function and later `pygame.init()` and other - see [template](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/blob/master/pygame/__template__/1__simple__.py)

Comment: use spaces around `=`, after `,` . Use `lower_case` names for functions and variables. Use english names for variables - see [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered:

```
    import pygame
import os

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
pygame.display.set_caption("shield hacking")
JogoAtivo = True
GAME_BEGIN = False
run =True
jumping =True;
# Speed in pixels per frame
speedX = 0
speedY = 0
cordX = 10;
cordY = 150;
groundX=0;
groundY=200;
verify = open('verify_continue.txt' , "r");


def loadCoords():
    f1 = open( "coords.txt", "r")
    text=f1.read()
    num_list=text.split()
    print (num_list)
    cordX=num_list[0]
    print(cordX)
    cordY=num_list[1]
    f1.close()  
    return cordX,cordY


def copiaArquivo(cordX, cordY):
  x=str(cordX);
  y=" "+str(cordY);
  f1 = open( 'coords.txt', "w")
  f1.write(x);
  f2 = open( 'coords.txt', "w")
  f2.seek(2)
  f2.write(y);
  f1.close()
  f2.close()


def draw():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    ground = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (groundX, groundY,400, 10))
    square = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (cordX, cordY ,50, 50))
    enemy = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 155), (200, 150 ,50, 50));
    pygame.display.flip();


""" SCREEN(press START)  """ 
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 55);
text = font.render("Press A to Start", 1, (255, 0, 0));
screen.blit(text,(50,20));
pygame.display.update();


while JogoAtivo:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        print(evento)

    #verifica se o evento que veio eh para fechar a janela
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
               JogoAtivo = False
               copiaArquivo(cordX, cordY);
               pygame.quit();
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if evento.key == pygame.K_a:
                   print('GAME BEGIN')
                   GAME_BEGIN = True
                   if verify.read()=="S":
                       cordX,cordY=loadCoords();
                       cordX = float(cordX);
                       cordY = float(cordY);
                   pygame.mixer.init();
                   sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound('GunsNRoses_ParadiseRemix_xD.wav');
                   chan1 = pygame.mixer.find_channel()
                   chan1.queue(sound1);
            if evento.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                   speedX=-0.006
                   run= True;
            if evento.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                   speedX=0.006
                   run= True;
            if evento.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                   print("x ", cordX)
                   print("y " ,cordY)
                   speedY=-0.3
                   jumping= True;
                   sound2 = pygame.mixer.Sound('MMX2_SE_00019.wav');
                   chan2 = pygame.mixer.find_channel();
                   chan2.queue(sound2);
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYUP:
             if evento.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                   speedY=+0.2




    if GAME_BEGIN:
        draw();
        if run == True:   
            cordX+=speedX
        if jumping == True:
            cordY+=speedY

    """square = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (cordX, cordY ,50, 50))
    enemy = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 155), (200, 150 ,50, 50));"""


    """ground detection"""
    if cordY +50>= groundY:
            speedY=0

    if cordX + 50 >=200 and cordX +50 <=250 and cordY < 100:
            speedX=0;

    if cordX + 50 >=200 and cordX +50 <=250 and cordY >= 100:
            speedY=0;
```